# Java GUI : Store names, while also being able to add more later on in the future

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable, jlist

Im tying to make a project were the user will input peoples names, and those names will be stored and the user will also be able to add more names in the future.  Im trying to think of a way of doing this with out using an array because then if I want to add more names in the future I wont be able to do this, but I haven’t came up with anything.  I was wondering if someone can point me out to the right direction.  Im trying to do this with GUI but most things use arrays, like jlist and jtable.

Comment: Why without an array?  Could you just use an `ArrayList` instead?

Comment: I should think it depends upon what your application is intended to be used for. If it's just names you want to acquire and store then a simple text file should suffice. If there is to be other data related to the name to also be added either currently of later on then perhaps a database would most likely be a better solution. There is nothing wrong with storing the names you acquire within an array (or better yet a collection) since you can iterate through that array (or collection) and save the data for later use.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an ArrayList. The syntax looks like this:

```
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, you can simply add items to the list be using:

```
objectList.add(objectThing);
```

This is similar to an array, in the sense that it stores multiple items of the same kind, but it operates differently and must be used differently. Please read up on ArrayLists and Lists for more information.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite reference when thinking about storing a collection of objects:
[image: This is my favorite reference when thinking about storing a collection of objects]

Sounds like you're going for values only, and duplicates are a possibility (user input) so you'll want an ArrayList as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48160116/4727762)